# I am trying to retrieve data from mongodb collection using nodejs but i have to request it twice to get the correct information

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, localhost

This is my code:
I have to request twice to get the data. Any problem? Thanks

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var input = "";
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url2 = "mongodb+srv://ramaty01:password@cluster0-hi4fv.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

http.createServer(function(req, res){
  if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
    res.end();
    console.log('favicon requested');
    return;
  }
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(
    "<html><head><title> MongoDB and NodeJS</title></head>" + 
    "<body><h1> COMPANY STOCK STICKER</h1><form>" + 
      "<input type='radio' id='company' name='types' value='company' required>" +
      "<label for='company'>Company Name</label><br>" + 
      "<input type='radio' id='stock' name='types' value='stock'>" + 
      "<label for='stock'>Stock Ticker</label><br><br>" +
      "<label for='txt'>Input: </label>" +
      "<input type='text' id='txt' name='txt'><br><br>" +
      "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>" +
    "</form><div id='output'></div></body></html>"
  );
  var qobj = url.parse(req.url, true).query;

  //var items;
  mong(qobj);
  res.write(input);
  res.end()
  input= "";
}).listen(8080);

function mong(qobj){

MongoClient.connect(url2, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db) {
    if(err) { console.log("Connection err: " + err); return; }
    var dbo = db.db("Company");
    var coll = dbo.collection('companies');
    var query;
    var inp = qobj.txt;
    if (qobj.types == "company") {
      query = { "company_name" : inp};
    } else if (qobj.types == "stock") {
      query = { "stock_ticker" : inp};
    }
    var s = coll.find(query,{projection: {"company_name":1, "stock_ticker":1, "_id":0}}).stream();

    s.on("data", function(item) {input = input + item.company_name + " " + item.stock_ticker;});
    s.on("end", function() {console.log("end of data");  db.close();});
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend that you immediately change your monogdb atlas password, and that you be more careful next time you're posting anything with sensitive information online.

With that being said, having worked with mongodb Atlas for sometime now, I've noticed that connection normally takes sometime, and that introduces some noticeable lag the fist time you fire up your server. That is probably what is happening, and since from your code I can't see evidence that your local server is waiting for this connection to happen before "serving" requests to your browser, there is no guarantee of the succession of events
To test this hypothesis, I suggest you wait for sometime before accessing the local server. This can be easily solved using an async function, or chaining a promise before starting your local server